# Using SSDT is it possible to have only selective scripts/objects maintained rather than maintaining the whole database?

Tags: sql-server, automation, sql-server-data-tools, sql-scripts, database-deployment

Is it possible for me to have a database project to maintain "only" a selective list of DB-objects or scripts rather than importing the entire/whole database?

I am tasked with writing an integration between some 3 - 4 third party applications. These applications have their own SQL databases. All I have to do is to add few new tables, write few new stored procedures, triggers, and UDFs.

Here are the things I am looking for:

An automated solution for change control, maintenance, and deployment of this subset of DB objects. (I am already using TFS so source control is not an issue.)

Can this be done using SSDT?

If not, are there other options open source?

Answer (score 1):

You can do but it isn't really ideal / if you can put all your objects in their own schema then it would be a bit easier but still a bit of a pain.

I have worked in a similar scenario and I just put everyone's code into the database project - when they do an update you sync back from the db to your project and as long as it isn't regular then it is normally fine.

If you can put everything in your own schema and you really can't put their code in your database project then use my filter and ignore all of their schemas ( https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/HOWTO-Filter-Dacpac-Deployments)

Finally if it is just a few objects then I probably wouldn't bother with ssdt - my rule of thumb to use ssdt is will you be changing the objects regularly or you want good validation then it probably isn't worth the effort.

You probably noticed the probablies in there, not every case is the same.

Sorry was a bit of a ramble!

Ed